# Save filters - should we use an icon and what should it look like?

Tags: mobile, icons, save

We are adding a save filters functionality for our mobile application. When the user clicks the save filters button we keep all of the currently selected filters so he can then use the same filters in the future.

Should we use an icon to trigger this feature or not? Our first thought was the classic save disk icon but we are not sure if it is the proper icon for that use.
Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Voting to close. Please see the [tour](http://ux.stackexchange.com/tour) regarding icon questions (see *don't ask* section.)

Comment: You could always just [combine the two](http://imgur.com/a/vG4I6).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you want people to actually use your new 'Save Filter' functionality (which BTW sounds like it could be a really useful feature for some users), so why do you think there is icon out there which succinctly communicates this feature's functionality? I doubt you will find any icon which is suitable.

Questions about *which* icon to use are banned here, but I want you to think about the user experience for a moment.

If you want people to use this Save Filter feature, I strongly recommend you make it obvious to the user that this feature exists.

The clearest way to promote the existence of this feature is to use a text link called "Save Filter". This is very short text link so will not take up much space, yet its purpose is abundantly clear.

Comment: hello @SteveD and thank you for your answer, also i have to apologize for not reading the rules before making this question.

Comment: i think you are right that we are not going to find a suitable icon